# How to unbold static methods in Visual Studio 2022 C# editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022, static class names, static methods and static properties are bold by default.  See this screenshot for example, the static method `GetRequired` is bold as well as the `InTestMode` static property and the `AppConfig` static class:

[image]

I'd like none of them to be bold.  But lets focus on the static method for a moment.  I know I can go into `Tools` > `Options` > `Environment` > `Fonts and Colors` and change the configuration of how various text elements are colored including bolding.  However I can not find the "Display Item" that controls the bolding of static code elements.   I have unchecked bold for all "Display Items" that start with "User Members - " including the one for "User Members - Methods" (shown below)

[image]

However, I'm still seeing the static methods as bold in the C# editor.  Which "Display Item" is the one that controls this bold treatment? Or is there a different way to turn this bold treatment off?

Comment: `InTestMode` is a field, not a method

Comment: Fair enough, but GetRequired is a static method.  I'll tweak my question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't really use Studio, but does it matter on the font selection at all? Or have you restarted the IDE after unchecking the bold box?

Comment: Has VS 2022 shipped yet?  That feature may not have made it into the _Fonts and Colors_ dialog yet

Comment: @OneCricketeer no, it's not based on the font.  I just tried Arial for fun and see the same issue.

Comment: @Flydog57 true, this is a Release Candidate not a final release but I have the same issue in VS2019 once adding VS2022 to my machine ;-)

Comment: @Orace Nope, no resharper on the machine.

Comment: Go find wherever MSFT records bugs on VS 2022.  Look to see if it's there.  If it isn't bug it

Comment: @Flydog57 That may be the answer but I hope it's not `cause the product is shipping this next week I think.

Comment: You can search for `static` in the top left text box. Apparently there is a `Symbol - static` entry in the * display items* list.

Comment: @oracle How did you search for it?  My top left box for searching in that dialog searches options not Display Items.  But anyway, I thought Symbol - static meant static text or a constant, etc.  But you are correct. That did in fact work.  Add that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/35401), static items style is overrided in the `Symbol - Static` entry. Since the bug is not fixed, the style will affect all static items.

For example: you can't have a static class declaration in bold without static members in bold too.

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice given the link you provided to the relevant repo conversation.  Wow!

Comment: @RonC, actually the 6th link on Google for `visual studio 2022 bold static method`. Yep I go to the deep when it's needed 

Comment: I guess that's the cool thing about SO and having multiple people search.  I just searched again for `visual studio 2022 bold static method` and based on however google is personalizing my results that result didn't show on page one, page two or page three of my results.  (I stopped looking after page three.)  So, I appreciate you searching for me -- apparently google likes you more than me :-)